Nuevamente sin moderadores
Pues la historia se repite, una vez más sin acción de los moderadores, a diferencia que esta vez si se supone que hay y están activos. ¿Hay solución?
Se están empezando a dar situaciones bastante poco agradables en comentarios y respuestas como hace un tiempo atrás, algo difícil de solucionar si no es por la acción de los moderadores. Lo peor es que si no hay freno, irá a más, perjudicando la actividad del sitio.

Si, lo sé, es una situación un poco particular y creo que hay un poco de desidia o desinterés por parte de los responsables del sitio. Respecto a tu comentario anterior, es preferible no generar enfrentamientos ni caer en el juego de los que lo provocan. Creo que a esta altura ya todos sabemos como funcionan algunos usuarios, es innecesario incidir en el tema. Mi apreciación en la pregunta es solo para mostrar una de las tantas necesidades de moderación del sitio.

Creo que no es muy activo en SpanishSE, quizás sea por el idioma, pero es una suposición.

I think if you see something abusive the system is for you to flag it. I think that works for comments as well. Obviously that depends on the moderators responding to the flag but I assume they get a notification. I am not sure from your question whether you have tried that and still failed to resolve the situation.

At the moment I have six flags accumulated for answers and comments, the oldest one from September 13th. This is one of the reasons for my post in this Meta.

Now you mention it I have one flag outstanding from September too. Not sure there is anything we can do at this point.

What can be done I have already done. I tried to contact the moderators through the flags, without response. Put the question on Big SE Meta, I have already done that. I followed the recommendations of what they propose on SE Meta, which is to contact SE through an email, and I also did that, without response. The only thing to do is to insist.

@mdewey
Well, I have received a reply from SE. In short, they have a way of knowing which sites are inactive from the moderators and they will be aware of what is happening in Spanish SE. We will have to be patient and try to ensure that all of us who actively participate continue to do so in the best possible way.

Danielillo Thank you for all your efforts on our behalf.

Si, estamos al borde del abismo. Intentaré elaborar una pregunta en el main Meta, pero es un poco difícil, principalmente por la diferencia de idioma, que hace complicado corroborar hechos.

It looks as though my outstanding flag from September has been handled now so fingers crossed.

I have three flags outstanding and the second comment under the question was written to me by tac. This is only one of several. And look how she addresses Danielillo right here: Dejá de llorar, papá. Then there is this by that same person here: La vieja afirmó dos veces en esa pregunta saber el uso de like, And Danielillo: I don't know who you mean by this: Creo que no es muy activo en SpanishSE, quizás sea por el idioma, pero es una suposición. Those comments to/about me are harassment.

Oops: he not she. Danielillo: I meant the comments by tac about me.

I have three outstanding flags as of Sept. this year.

I know. Regarding the "harassment", it is a comment that in a normal situation is deleted and the author alerted (at least) but we are not facing a normal situation. I already wrote to SE, and their response is that the moderators are active, but that is not what is really happening. I recommend you write a post on MetaSE or send an email to SE.
